# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction fee payer required

Tags: javascript, solana, solana-web3js, phantom-wallet

I get this error when I try to execute this using phantom wallet and react app

```
  const transferTransaction = new Transaction()
  .add(SystemProgram.transfer({
    fromPubkey: alice.publicKey,
    toPubkey: feePayer.publicKey,
    lamports: lamportsToSend
  }))
  
  const network = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(network);
const transaction = new Transaction();
transferTransaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getRecentBlockhash()).blockhash;

const { signature } = await window.solana.signAndSendTransaction(transferTransaction);
await connection.confirmTransaction(signature);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

transferTransaction.feePayer = alice.publicKey

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i answered the same question 1month before his answer, but my answer was deleted :-|